# css nth-of-type every first, second, third in a long list

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a dynamic list that is being generated that may or may not be many lines so lets say this:

```
<div class="timeline-block">
    <div class="timeline-dot">TEST</div>
</div>
<div class="timeline-block">
    <div class="timeline-dot">TEST</div>
</div>
<div class="timeline-block">
    <div class="timeline-dot">TEST</div>
</div>
<div class="timeline-block">
    <div class="timeline-dot">TEST</div>
</div>
<div class="timeline-block">
    <div class="timeline-dot">TEST</div>
</div>
<div class="timeline-block">
    <div class="timeline-dot">TEST</div>
</div>
<div class="timeline-block">
    <div class="timeline-dot">TEST</div>
</div>
<div class="timeline-block">
    <div class="timeline-dot">TEST</div>
</div>
<div class="timeline-block">
    <div class="timeline-dot">TEST</div>
</div>
```

I need to alternate the background of every 1st, 2nd, and 3rd of type indefinitely. I always struggle with nth-of-type formulas so what I have right now is not working. It gets the first three items correct, but starts missing the count after that. Here is the css/scss...

```
.timeline-block:nth-of-type(1n) {
    .timeline-dot {
        background: blue;
    }
}

.timeline-block:nth-of-type(2n) {
    .timeline-dot {
        background: red;
    }
}

.timeline-block:nth-of-type(3n) {
    .timeline-dot {
        background: green;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're after is the offset of the nth-of-type selector `(Xn + Y)`

To get the effect you're after, just bump the offset value by one for each of the three variations.

```
.timeline-block:nth-of-type(3n) {
  background: green;
}

.timeline-block:nth-of-type(3n + 1) {
  background: red;
}

.timeline-block:nth-of-type(3n + 2) {
  background: blue;
}
```

Here's a [codepen](https://codepen.io/monners/pen/BYyELv)

Comment: No problem.  `nth-of-type` can be a little counter-intuitive

Comment: so to add a 4th color I just increase my Xn to 4 and then increment accordingly right?

Comment: Nah, then you'll have to up your iteration selector to `4n`, otherwise you'll be overlapping previous selectors.  So for four it'd look like `nth-of-type(4n) / (4n + 1) / (4n + 2) / (4n + 3)`

Answer (score 2):

It's `3n+1`, `3n+2` and `3n`

(in the snippet it's not possible to nest the selectors like in SCSS):

```css
.timeline-block:nth-of-type(3n+1) .timeline-dot {
  background: blue;
}

.timeline-block:nth-of-type(3n+2) .timeline-dot {
  background: red;
}

.timeline-block:nth-of-type(3n) .timeline-dot {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="timeline-block">
  <div class="timeline-dot">TEST</div>
</div>
<div class="timeline-block">
  <div class="timeline-dot">TEST</div>
</div>
<div class="timeline-block">
  <div class="timeline-dot">TEST</div>
</div>
<div class="timeline-block">
  <div class="timeline-dot">TEST</div>
</div>
<div class="timeline-block">
  <div class="timeline-dot">TEST</div>
</div>
<div class="timeline-block">
  <div class="timeline-dot">TEST</div>
</div>
<div class="timeline-block">
  <div class="timeline-dot">TEST</div>
</div>
<div class="timeline-block">
  <div class="timeline-dot">TEST</div>
</div>
<div class="timeline-block">
  <div class="timeline-dot">TEST</div>
</div>
```